# Bind checkboxes in listview MVVM

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am trying to bind checkbox as below but when I click on it it doesn't even stay checked.Below is my model that maps to the db.I would like to get selected item using the checked checkboxes so I can eventually grab the cost fields.I have attempted to follow the code example from [Programming Windows Store Apps with C#.](https://github.com/mbrit/ProgrammingWindowsStoreApps)
by Matt Baxter-Reynolds and Iris Classon.I have updated my code to match answer provided by @Arnaud.The checkbox doesn't stay checked but the visibility of the button changes on clicking on the radiobuttons.

**Model ServiceItem**

```
     public class ServiceItem:ModelItem
    {
        // key field...
        [AutoIncrement(), PrimaryKey(), JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        // other fields...
        [Unique, JsonProperty("id")]
        public int NativeId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost
      {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<decimal>();
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
        }
      }
      [JsonIgnore] //prefer not to have it on db has no value
      public bool IsSelected
     {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<bool>();
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
        }
     }

        public ServiceItem()
        {
        }
    }
```

Below is the Viewmodel

**ServicesPage ViewModel**

```
    public class ServicesPageViewModel : ViewModel, IServicesPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public ICommand ContinueCommand { get; private set; }
    public ServicesPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public override void Initialize(IViewModelHost host)
    {
        base.Initialize(host);
        // setup...
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ServiceItem>();

        this.ContinueCommand = new DelegateCommand((args) => GetSelected(args as CommandExecutionContext));

    }

}
```

Below is the xaml
**ServicePage.xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="true"                      
                  Margin="10,10,10,0" TabIndex="1">                
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"  
                                  BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="1">

**Viewmodel**

```
public abstract class ViewModel : ModelItem, IViewModel
    {
        //  somewhere to hold the host...
        protected IViewModelHost Host { get; private set; }
    //other code omitted
    }
```

**Viewmodel interface Iviewmodel**

```
 public interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        void Initialize(IViewModelHost host);
    //other code omitted
    }
```

**ModelItem**

```
public abstract class ModelItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }

    protected ModelItem()
    {
        this.Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (this.Values.ContainsKey(name))
            return (T)this.Values[name];
        else
            return default(T);
    }

    protected void SetValue(object value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        // set...
        this.Values[name] = value;

        // notify...
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class `ServiceItem` otherwise you will never raise any event when the value is updated.

Here is the code of my view. I have added a converter to display the cost only when items are selected:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.CheckBoxPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="true"                      
                  Margin="10,10,10,0" TabIndex="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"  
                                  BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

And the classes, I have used. `ServiceItem` needs to extend `ModelItem` so as to notify the view of changes on properties *Cost* and *IsSelected*. Without it, the View will only get the initial values of *Cost* and *IsSelected* and all updates on these properties will be ignored by the View.

```
public sealed partial class CheckBoxPage : Page
{
    public CheckBoxPage()
    {
        var items = new ObservableCollection<ServiceItem>()
        {
            new ServiceItem() {Name = "Item 1", Id = 1, NativeId = 1, Cost = 123 },
            new ServiceItem() {Name = "Item 2", Id = 2, NativeId = 2, Cost = 456 },
            new ServiceItem() {Name = "Item 3", Id = 3, NativeId = 3, Cost = 789 },
            new ServiceItem() {Name = "Item 4", Id = 4, NativeId = 4, Cost = 1011 },
        };

        Items = items;

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ServiceItem : ModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NativeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<decimal>();
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<bool>();
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have Inotifypropertychanged on my interface IViewModel.Let me add it for completeness @Amaud

Comment: Yes, but you still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on classes  used by your ViewModel.

Comment: the ServicesPageViewModel implements ViewModel which implements IViewModel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yes, but it is not enough. For example, check this model class: https://github.com/mbrit/ProgrammingWindowsStoreApps/blob/master/Chapter08/StreetFoo.Client/StreetFoo.Client/Model/Instances/SearchFilter.cs . It extends `ModelItem` class so as to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the following properties : *Description* and *Active*. I have updated my **ServiceItem** class in my answer to use your model classes. For example, *Active* property is declared as `public bool Active { get { return this.GetValue<bool>(); } internal set { this.SetValue(value); } }`

Comment: @Amaud thanks for your patience.The visibility is working on the checked item but the curious thing is it doesn't stay checked.That's why I never noticed if it was working.Any idea why?

Comment: No, I have not reproduced this issue. Sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115190/discussion-between-gotalovecode-and-arnaud-develay).

Comment: For anyone who reads this and does the same idiotic mistake.The check in the checkbox was white on a white background and foreground color set to black only makes the text content black not the tick itself.#MyRookieMistakes101